# some(element) with publishing which elements is true

Tags: javascript

i have this code which checks elements in array and determine their existance (true,false), but i want to know which element is exist, how can i achieve that ?
the output should be : true, hi
the code:

```
var str1 = 'hi, how do you do?';

// does the test strings contains this terms?
var conditions = ["hello", "hi", "howdy"];

// run the tests agains every element in the array
var test1 = conditions.some(el => str1.includes(el));
document.write(str1, ' ===> ', test1);
```

--
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `.filter` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find()` instead of `some()`

**Note:** `find()` will get only the single(first) element of array which matches condition. If no element matches condition it return `undefined`

```js
var str1 = 'hi, how do you do?';

// does the test strings contains this terms?
var conditions = ["hello", "hi", "howdy"];

// run the tests agains every element in the array
var test1 = conditions.find(el => str1.includes(el));
console.log(test1)
```

If you want to get all the elements of array which matches condition then use `filter()`

```js
var str1 = 'hi, how do you do? howdy';

// does the test strings contains this terms?
var conditions = ["hello", "hi", "howdy"];

// run the tests agains every element in the array
var test1 = conditions.filter(el => str1.includes(el));
console.log(test1)
```